# Linprog error-Matlab

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I just tried to solve a simple linear programming problem using matlab, It is pretty easy:

Find x that minimizes f(x) = –5x1 – 4x2 –6x3, subject to

```
x1 – x2 + x3 ≤ 20
3x1 + 2x2 + 4x3 ≤ 42
3x1 + 2x2 ≤ 30
0 ≤ x1, 0 ≤ x2, 0 ≤ x3.
```

%mfile: First, enter the coefficient

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
f = [-5; -4; -6];
A =  [1 -1  1
  3  2  4
  3  2  0];
b = [20; 42; 30];
lb=zeros(3,1);
x = linprog(f,A,b,[],[],lb);
```

when I run this program it doesn't return x values, and returns this error:

```
Error in linprog1 (line 10)
x = linprog(f,A,b,[],[],lb);
```

what's the problem, my matlab have optimization toolbox, why it doesn't know linprog? what should I do now?

Thank you all

-Maryam

Comment: Is that the *complete* error message? Is `linprog1` the name of your MATLAB function, or is it something internal to MATLAB's `linprog`? (I guess the former since that call to `linprog` is on line 10 of the code listed here.)

Comment: The MATLAB documentation seems to indicate that if you provide lower bounds you should also provide upper bounds; does adding an extra `,[]` to the arguments you pass to `linprog` help?

Comment: Er, or perhaps it needs to be `[inf; inf; inf]` rather than `[]`.

Comment: linprog1 is just the name of my m-file.  it returns exactly this error: 
Error in linprog1 (line 10)
x = linprog(f,A,b,[],[],lb);

Comment: Yes I added now, [] and tried [inf; inf; inf] as well and it still returns this error: 
Error in linprog1 (line 10)
x = linprog(f,A,b,[],[],lb,[inf; inf; inf]);

Comment: my matlab version is 2012-is it possible that its optimization toolbox doesn't work? then what should I do?

Comment: I'm still baffled by your error message. There isn't *anything else* at all either before it or after it? Usually when MATLAB says something like that, it's part of a longer message. I don't think I've ever seen it just say "Error in [location]" without any information about what the error *is*. Are you absolutely certain there isn't any other text that could tell us more about what MATLAB doesn't like?

Comment: I hope that could send the screen shot of my program and error.. it has nothing before or after this error..

Comment: I don't know exactly when `linprog` was introduced, but it was well before 2012 so your problem really shouldn't be that you don't have `linprog`.

Comment: After it's failed with this mysterious "Error in linprog1", if you type `MException.last` into the MATLAB console, what does it say?

Comment: And another problem that I understood now, is that when I close matlab and open my m-file, at first current folder changes to my E:\, where I saved my m-file. when I run the program, it automatically changes the current folder to place which I installed matlab. I have never seen this problem with any other m-files.

Comment: after typing MException.last it says: 

  Properties:
    identifier: ''
       message: 'wrong dimensions'
         cause: {0x1 cell}
         stack: [2x1 struct]

Comment: OK. And if you now type `getReport(MException.last)` what does it say?

Comment: it says: 
ans =

Error using linprog (line 35)
wrong dimensions

Error in linprog1 (line 10)
x = linprog(f,A,b,[],[],lb);

Comment: Is it possible that the name of linprog is not linprog in this version of matlab? just now I ran tone of optimization toolbox demos "Using Quadratic Programming on Portfolio Optimization Problems", and I gained outputs without error, I checked this demo, it doesn't include the term linprog!!

Comment: I'm pretty sure `linprog` has been there, under that name, since something like 2007 at least.

Comment: Try making your bounds and the `f` coefficients *row vectors* instead of column vectors. The [MATLAB documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html) seems to have it that way. If `linprog` is expecting that, it might explain a "wrong dimensions" message.

Comment: I need to solve linear programming problems and my linprog doesn't work.. i really don't know what to do.. it runs all demos except linprog!

Comment: f is now a row vector and error message is: 
Error using linprog (line 35)
wrong dimensions

Error in linprog1 (line 10)
x=linprog(f,A,b,[],[],lb)

Comment: And if you also include the upper as well as the lower bounds? Another thing to try, just to see what it tells us: what if you just ask for `linprog(f,A,b)` without the other parameters? Of course that will be solving the wrong problem, but it may give some insight into where the problem is.

Comment: I included upper bound as well, the message is: 
Error using linprog
Too many input arguments.

Error in linprog1 (line 10)
x=linprog(f,A,b,[],[],lb,[]);

and when I typed linprog(f,A,b) the message was: Error using linprog (line 35)
wrong dimensions

Error in linprog1 (line 10)
linprog(f,A,b)

Comment: Hm. So here's a thing. If you do a web search for "linprog.m" you will find something from 2002, which expects its arguments in a different order from those of the `linprog` in the Optimization Toolbox. And on line 35 of that `linprog.m` there is a check that can produce the message "wrong dimensions". You might want to have a look and see if there is a `linprog.m` somewhere in your working directory or your MATLAB path. If so, either (1) move it, (2) rename it, or (3) use it instead of MATLAB's own `linprog` (which would mean changing how you call it).

Comment: Ooohhh, you are reeeeaaalllly a geniusssss, Thanks a mmiiillion, happy lllinprog.. Thank you, Thank you, God give you anyyything that you wish..

Comment: Thanks! I'll put this into an answer.

Comment: Yes Thanks. put it into an answer. it was most mysterious error I had ever seen..

Comment: Done. Glad I could help.

Comment: I will pray for you tonight, that God give you anythinggg that your heart wants. Thanks a bunch. Bye.

Comment: My heart wants you to accept my answer by clicking the little green checkmark :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation (see comments to the original question for details) it transpired that as well as the MATLAB Optimization Toolbox's `linprog`, the questioner *also* had on her computer a copy of something like [this linprog.m](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2166-introduction-to-linear-algebra/content/strang/linprog.m) -- which I suspect is an ancestor of what's now in the Optimization Toolbox, but takes its arguments in a different order.

Either the "old" `linprog.m` or the one in the OT is capable of solving the questioner's linear program. So the options are:

- Use the "old" one, adjusting the code appropriately.
- Remove (or move elsewhere, or rename) the "old" one and use the one in the Optimization Toolbox.